# iterative lookup from within rdd.map in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
def retrieveindex (stringlist: List[String], lookuplist: List[String]) = 
  stringlist.foreach(y => lookuplist.indexOf(y))
```

is my function.

I am trying to use this within an rdd like this:

```
val libsvm = libsvmlabel.map(x => 
  Array(x._2._2,retrieveindex(x._2._1.toList,featureSet.toList)))
```

However, I am getting an output that is empty. There is no error, but the output from retrieveindex is empty. When I use println to see if I am retrieving correctly, I do see the indices printed. Is there any way to do this? Should I first 'distribute' the function to all the workers? I am a newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`retrieveindex` has a return type of type `Unit` (because of `foreach` which just applies a function `(String) ⇒ Unit` on each element). Therefore it does not map to anything.

You probably want it to return the list of indices, like:

```
def retrieveindex(stringlist: List[String], lookuplist: List[String]): List[Int] = 
  stringlist.map(y => lookuplist.indexOf(y))
```

Comment: you nailed it - yes, I figured the problem was return type Unit but didn't know how to fix it. Thanks a ton.